# how to use orOperator in mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-criteria

below is mongo document structure,

```
{_id:123,imageShared:{imageId:345,likeCount:2,rateMedia:{rateVal1:1}}}
{_id:124,imageShared:{imageId:346,likeCount:3,rateMedia:{rateVal2:3}}}
{_id:125,imageShared:{imageId:347,likeCount:3}}
```

Now i need to get the documents which has rateVal1,rateVal2 fields.
For that i did below code...

```
Query condition = new Query();
condition.addCriteria(
Criteria.where("imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal1").exists(true).
orOperator(Criteria.where("imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal2").exists(true));
```

I am not getting the documents as i am expecting _id of 123,124 documents.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the output you are getting now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need get the equivalent of the query

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [ 
        { "imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal1": { "$exists": true } }, 
        { "imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal2": { "$exists": true } }
    ] 
})
```

so you should try the following

```
Query condition = new Query(
        new Criteria()
        .orOperator(
            Criteria.where("imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal1").exists(true),
            Criteria.where("imageShared.rateMedia.rateVal2").exists(true)
        )
    );
```